# specify VSTOLocal string for Manifest registry entry in VSTO Addin deployment using Clickonce

Tags: excel, vsto, clickonce

I have developed a VSTO Excel Application level Addin that gets installed by Clickonce installer.

I always want the Addin to use the VSTO file that is available in the installation location rather than using from the clickonce cache. This can be achieved by appending the value "|VSTOLocal" to Manifest registry key of the Addin. After the installing the Addin i see the Manifest registry entry to be

file:///C:/Users/XXX/Desktop/TestAddin/TestAddin.vsto

This is want to change it to

file:///C:/Users/XXX/Desktop/TestAddin/TestAddin.vsto|VstoLocal

At present i need to do this manually but Is there any way of doing this via the clickonce installer i know i can do this with MSI package but i want to keep the set up simple. Is there any setting etc in visual studio that will help me to append this string to the manifest key??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. ClickOnce doesn't provide custom actions like Windows Installer does.

Comment: Thanks Eugene .. Did some more research and found no way to do this via click once.... Looks like i have to create an installer for this.. !!!